# I am receiving an error when trying to build a docker image from a project in Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to Devops and I am trying to build a Docker image in a self-hosted gitlab instance. I have installed Gitlab from Docker image, I have installed gitlab-runner from Docker image and I can see the runner inside Gitlab and I have configured it for a certain project, I created a gitlab-ci.yml file and went to jobs to build the project to a Docker image. It says running for a few second after that it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to remove network for build
ERROR: Preparation failed: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker 
daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get 
http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.25/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: 
permission denied (docker.go:858:0s)
```

I have tried a solution to give permision with this command:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Here is the gitlab-ci.yml file content:

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on 
your project.
# Build a Docker image with CI/CD and push to the GitLab registry.
# Docker-in-Docker documentation: 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html
#
# This template uses one generic job with conditional builds
# for the default branch and all other (MR) branches.
docker-build:
# Use the official docker image.
image: docker:latest
stage: build
services:
- docker:dind
before_script:
- docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" 
$CI_REGISTRY
# Default branch leaves tag empty (= latest tag)
# All other branches are tagged with the escaped branch name (commit 
ref slug)
script:
- |
  if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH" ]]; then
    tag=""
    echo "Running on default branch '$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH': tag = 
'latest'"
  else
    tag=":$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    echo "Running on branch '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH': tag = $tag"
  fi
- docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}" .
- docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE${tag}"
# Run this job in a branch where a Dockerfile exists
rules:
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
  exists:
    - Dockerfile
```

And after that I retried to build the project but I get the same error.

Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your .gitlab-ci.yml? or maybe partially

Comment: I modified the question with the added content of the file